# Connecting interrupts to table elements

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble [here](http://jsfiddle.net/neAUZ/2/) connecting interrupts to table elements.

It seems that clicking "Delete cell" or "Open helper" should fire one of the handlers, but nothing happens. The Open helper td has two chances to fire a handler, once for the row it's in and once for the td it's in.

Does anyone see the problem?

Thanks.

The jsfiddle is perfectly clear but the forum wants code if there's a jsfiddle link, so here:

```
$(document).on('click','tr.deleteCell', function(event) {
  alert("deleting cell");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery `on` was not introduced until version 1.7, while your fiddle sources 1.6.2.  [See the docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

If you change the jQuery for a version 1.7+, the click handler for `tr.deleteCell` will work.

The other two handlers are applied incorrectly.  They both are looking `.td`, which would be an element with class "td", not necessarily a td element.

Comment: Thanks.  The real issue for me was the dots in front of the selectors. My code actually uses jQuery 1.91.  It was an old jsfiddle I modified for the demo. Many thanks to you and to PSL below for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

YOu need to upgrade your Jquery to support [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Apart from this there are some selector issues.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uRUVR/)

`.tr.openHelper` doesn't need a dot in front of tr and similarly with `.td.openh`

This should work provided you upgrade your jquery.

```
$(document).on('click', 'tr.deleteCell', function (event) {
    alert("deleting cell");
});

$(document).on('click', 'tr.openHelper', function (event) {
    alert("opening helper");
});

$(document).on('click', 'td.openh', function (event) {
    alert("opening helper from td");
});
```

With your version of jquery you should go with `live` or just `click` event

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LW7BQ/)

```
$('tr.deleteCell').live('click',function (event) {
    alert("deleting cell");
});

$('tr.openHelper').live('click',  function (event) {
    alert("opening helper");
});

$('td.openh').live('click', function (event) {
    alert("opening helper from td");
});
```